# simple preg_match begin...end

Tags: php, preg-match-all

I ned to catch all occurancy of "object" in suche code:

```
object InvalidFilterField3: TUNIField
  FieldType = uftString
  FieldName = 'PRI_SERIAL'
  Caption = sdfgsdfgsdfg
  Category = sdfgsdfgsdfgsdfg
  Opers = [opEqual, opLike, opInList, opIsNull, opIsNotNull]
  DefaultOper = opLike
  FieldIndex = 0
end
object UNIField1: TUNIField
  FieldType = uftDate
  FieldName = 'PRI_DT'
  Caption = sdfgsdfgsdfg
  Category = asdfasdfasdfasdf
  Opers = [opEqual, opNotEqual, opLarger, opSmaller, opEqualOrLarger, opEqualOrSmaller, opBetween, opIsNull, opIsNotNull, opIn]
  DefaultOper = opEqual
  FieldIndex = 1
end
```

think that must be `/object(.*)end/m` but it does not =(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to pass up into the pattern both the dotall modifier (**s**) to tell PCRE that a dot means *anything* (including newlines) and the ungreedy modifier (**U**, more on greediness and modifiers on [the PHP manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php)):

```
preg_match_all('!object(.*)end!sU', $string, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

Comment: youe example prints `Array ( [0] => Array ( ) [1] => Array ( ) )`

Comment: True, just fixed it. Even though as I explained you must use both s and U modifiers, I just used U in the example. :-)

Comment: tnx. this resolves the main problem. just one more question: what if there are nested objects `object .... object ... end object end end`?